# Deleting files from terminal; output displays files skipped opposed to files deleted

Tags: macos, terminal, delete-file, recycle-bin

OS: Mac Mojave 10.14.3

I have recently begun teaching myself python, and have written a command that I execute after updating packages to recursively clear out the "pycache" folders.  The command uses the "trash" formula from homebrew.

```
cd '/Library/Frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.7'
find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -exec trash {} \;
```

The command works great, but my question is regarding the output terminal displays when its running. Instead of showing every directory that is being deleted, it only displays directories being skipped because they don't contain "pycache" folders. Why is the output backwards like this?

For reference here is a portion of the output:

```
find: ./lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/__pycache__: No such file or directory
find: ./lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__pycache__: No such file or directory
find: ./lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/__pycache__: No such file or directory
find: ./lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/__pycache__: No such file or directory
find: ./lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/backports/__pycache__: No such file or directory
find: ./lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/__pycache__: No such file or directory
```

Thanks

Comment: That output is a info/warning message from the `find` command itself. I think the actual output is consumed by the `trash` formula and not printed.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`trash` is silent by default. If you want it to be verbose, use the [`-v` option](https://github.com/ali-rantakari/trash/blob/6bbecd4147bf91386c297095ba2f29887dd36022/trash.pod):

```
trash -v
```

The full command now looks like this:

```
cd '/Library/Frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.7'
find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -exec trash -v {} \;
```